# Extracting pieces of information from faces

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I need to extract person features from photos.
Features that I care about:

- sex
- race
- age
- hair color*
- eye color*

(Features with * is nice to have but it's not necessary)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What do you need? A Python library? Or an application? Any price tag for the latter, or license concerns for the former?

Comment: I don't really care about language that software is written, but it should be opensource and it should be able to be called from a terminal but it's not necessary because I can write that by my own